# Change Library Icon in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, libraries

Is it possible to change library icons in Windows 8 ? Has the process changed since Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 8 actually has a simpler method to change icons than Windows 7:

1. Right-click the library whose icon you want to change.
2. Click `Change library icon...` button. This button was not present in Windows 7.
   [image]
3. Select the icon that you want.
4. Click `OK` button.